Issues with one time quartz .net job
I'm using .NET 8 and I'm trying to setup a Quartz Job.
What I want to achieve is that in production, this job must be scheduled (with a cron schedule), but in dev and in local I don't need it scheduled, but I still need it to be registered because I want to be able to run a OneTimeJob from a Controller endpoint.
This is my setup:
Inside the Startup.cs
        var environmentType = Environment.Type;
        services.AddQuartz();
        services.AddQuartzHostedService(opt =>
        {
            opt.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
        });

        if (Environment.Type == EnvironmentType.Production)
        {
            services.ConfigureOptions<ProcessIssuersJobSetupWithCron>();
        }
        else if (environmentType is EnvironmentType.TestingRc or EnvironmentType.TestingMaster or EnvironmentType.Staging or EnvironmentType.Local)
        {
            services.ConfigureOptions<ProcessIssuersJobSetupWithoutCron>();
        }

Let's focus on the WithoutCron job:
public class ProcessIssuersJobSetupWithoutCron : IConfigureOptions<QuartzOptions>
{
    public void Configure(QuartzOptions options)
    {
        var processIssuersJobKey = JobKey.Create("ProcessIssuersJob");

        options
            .AddJob<ProcessIssuersJob>(jobBuilder => jobBuilder.WithIdentity(processIssuersJobKey))
            .AddTrigger(trigger =>
                trigger
                    .ForJob(jobKey: processIssuersJobKey));
    }
}

And from my Controller I try to trigger that in this way:
public class QuartzController(ISchedulerFactory scheduleFactory) : Controller
{
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory _scheduleFactory = scheduleFactory;

    [HttpPost("ProcessIssuers")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExecuteDataStoredProcedures([FromQuery] DateTime runDate)
    {
        var scheduler = await this._scheduleFactory.GetScheduler();
        var jobKey = JobKey.Create("ProcessIssuersJob");

        var jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
        jobDataMap.Put("runDate", runDate);

        await scheduler.TriggerJob(jobKey, jobDataMap);

        return this.Ok();
    }
}

but when it comes to the await.scheduler.TriggerJob(jobKey, jobDataMap); I'm getting this error:
Exception Type: Quartz.JobPersistenceException
Error message: The job (DEFAULT.ProcessIssuersJob) referenced by the trigger does not exist.

I tried to debug and it actually arrives inside the ProcessIssuersJobSetupWithoutCron Configure method, and the key is the same: DEFAULT.ProcessIssuersJob .
What am I doing wrong? I'm not 100% but I think when I was using the ProcessIssuersWithCron it was working the one time job.. here's the setup with cron::
public class ProcessIssuersJobSetupWithCron : IConfigureOptions<QuartzOptions>
{
    private static readonly string MonthlyJobCronExpression;

    static ProcessIssuersJobSetupWithCron()
    {
        MonthlyJobCronExpression = AppSettingBuilder<string>
            .Create("MonthlyJobCronExpression", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
            .ToSetting()
            .Value;
    }

    public void Configure(QuartzOptions options)
    {
        var processIssuersJobKey = JobKey.Create("ProcessIssuersJob");

        if (MonthlyJobCronExpression.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            return;
        }

        options
            .AddJob<ProcessIssuersJob>(jobBuilder => jobBuilder.WithIdentity(processIssuersJobKey))
            .AddTrigger(trigger =>
                trigger
                    .ForJob(jobKey: processIssuersJobKey)
                    .WithCronSchedule(MonthlyJobCronExpression, cron => cron.InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc)));
    }
}


The Quartz.Job is not executed when the webapplication is started. You can add StartNow and try again.

I don't need it to start when the application starts. I need to get registered and never start until I trigger the endpoint. It will be a huge problem if it starts at the start of the application, because it triggers a data job working with tons of sql data which can last days. So I just need it to get registered and be able to trigger one time job when I call the endpoint
